# DataGrid Hidden Rows still "visible" - redorder possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a little tool to keep an eye on printer errors e.g. paper jam, low toner etc.

To hold all available printers, I'm using a Datagrid bound to a `ObservableCollection`. To show/hide, the `DataGridRow.Style` is bound to `PrintQueueStatus` so `if status != none` the row is visible.

My Problem is the following

[image: Datagrid with problem]

As you can see, the lines are hidden as I wanted but the visible lines wont get reordered, so I've a lot of blank rows.

My question here, is it possible Hide the rows like ther weren't there? I just want the visible rows in my Datagrid.

I know I Could of course delete all Items out of the ObservableCollection which are not of interest but I want to know if it's possible to do it in XAML.

Comment: How do you set the lines to invisible? `Visibility.Hidden` or `Visibility.Collapsed?`

Comment: Well, i changed that and yea it works, that made my day, thank you xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
see there,you will get to know the difference between them
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visibility.aspx